# How to parse part of .then() as a other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've got a part of code which repeats few times in my code: The function:

```
exports.getCategoryProducts = (req, res) => {
db.collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", req.params.category)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    //duplicate code starts
    .then((data) => {
        let products = [];
        data.forEach((doc) => {
            products.push({
                id: doc.id,
                title: doc.data().title,
                category: doc.data().category,
                description: doc.data().description,
                image: doc.data().image,
                price: doc.data().price,
                rating: doc.data().rating,
            });
        });
        return res.status(200).json(products);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Something went wrong, please try again later",
        });
    });
    //duplicate code ends
};
```

How can I extract the part I've marked and use it as a function in other API requests?

Comment: You could make a callback function  `cb` that takes the data and does everything in `.then`. Similar for the error. Then use it with `.then(cb).catch(cbErr)`

Comment: A `.forEach()` that always `.push()`es something into an array should be a `.map()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a handler which receives the data as parameter and returns the transformed data

```
function dataHandler(data) {
  return data.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            title: doc.data().title,
            category: doc.data().category,
            description: doc.data().description,
            image: doc.data().image,
            price: doc.data().price,
            rating: doc.data().rating,
  }));
}


function getCategoryProducts((req, res) => {
  db.collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", req.params.category)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(data => dataHandler(data))
    .then(products => {
      res.status(200).json(products);
    })
    .catch(e => {...});
}
```

And if this code is always called in the context of an express handler, you can even pass `res` to the `dataHandler` and if you are always returning the same error, you could also create an standard `errorHandler`

```
function dataHandler(data, res) {
  res.status(200).json(data.map(doc => {
       let dd = doc.data();
       return {
            id: doc.id,
            title: dd.title,
            category: dd.category,
            description: dd.description,
            image: dd.image,
            price: dd.price,
            rating: dd.rating,
       }
     }));
}

function errorHandler(err, res) {
  console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
        message: "Something went wrong, please try again later",
    });
}

function getCategoryProducts((req, res) => {
  db.collection("products")
    .where("category", "==", req.params.category)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(data => dataHandler(data, res))
    .catch(e => errorHandler(e, res));
}
```